Problem with writing SQL query (Group by, Distinct)
I have a table with three columns. The table describes the various advertisements that the company has.
The first column is advertising, which displays the number of advertisements that is shown to the user.
The second click column shows whether the user clicked on the advertisement or not (1 - clicked, 0 - not) in the third -  country in which the user is located (not important for the request).
Please note that one advertisement can be displayed several times.
I need to write a query that displays how many advertisements there are with 1 click, two clicks, and so on.
So I need to get a result:
3 | 0
6 | 1
1 | 2
enter image description here
The best option I could come up with is this one but it diesn't give a desicion that I need
SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT commercial), SUM(click) FROM Table1 Group by commercial  ;



Please replace images with formatted text in addition to provide desired output as formatted text.

There are actually only 3 commercials with 0 clicks (1, 3, and 8). I suspect you included 5 and 9. 5 has 1 click in the US and 9 has 1 click in Israel. One way to verify is to see if the first column adds up to 10.

yes. you are right, fixed in the question

Maybe this query works.

SELECT
  A.clicks,
  count(*) as comercials
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      commercial,
      SUM(CAST(click as INT)) as clicks
  FROM
      Advertising
  GROUP BY
      commercial
) as A
GROUP BY
  A.clicks
;



I added it to my fiddle for comparison. It works! I think the CTE version is more compact and readable. Subqueries are best when they are used for filtering in the WHERE clause (CTE don't work there) or when they act as a column. https://dbfiddle.uk/EI4kNVKi

WITH ComericalClicks as
(  
SELECT commercial, SUM(click) as SumClick FROM Table1 Group by commercial  
)
SELECT count(*) Count, SumClick
FROM ComericalClicks
GROUP BY SumClick

fiddle



Count
SumClick




3
0


6
1


1
2




fiddle with more steps to prove solution https://dbfiddle.uk/xf9LXra1

thanks, it works. I'm starting a SQL course, and I got this task from the school before I started to learn, they are checking my self-learn abilities. It looks a little bit complicated for somebody that never coded on SQL..
